# How to update arguments of an already started apscheduler job?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a function called 'run' that runs for several hours and receive an argument 'param', as shown in the code below. How can I change param while the job is running?

```
sched1 = BackgroundScheduler()
sched1.add_job(run, 'interval', hours = 5, args=[param])
sched1.start()
```

Regards

Comment: May I ask what the use case is, and why the job is running for several hours?

Answer (score 0):

If `param` is mutable, and you're not using an executor that runs in another process, you can just mutate the `param` object wherever it is that you want to mutate it. You just need to keep a reference to it around somewhere outside of the job. But there is no mechanism in APScheduler to change the argument set in a job that is already running (that would be impossible).